# Unit Testing Entity Framework DBContext Override Methods

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, nunit, moq

I have a `DBContext` Class file via Entity Framework that represents my database.

Inside this class I have method called `SoftDelete` that is called within my overridden method of the `SaveChanges` method

`SaveChanges` Method:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(){
    SoftDelete();
}
```

`SoftDelete` Method:

```
private void SoftDelete(DbEntityEntry entry)        {
   //If **some condition** THEN: Mark deleted time stamps on database table.
}
```

I am fairly new to unit testing using Moq and NUnit. I would like to know how I can write a Unit test using MOQ and NUnit around this method. Should the "Some Condition" change, I need to make sure that my test will pass to avoid the risk of having data loss in our database.

Thanks

Comment: i can give you an example but just i have question for you why you do not have an interceptor for the soft delete?!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by interceptor? can you provide a link explaining what you  mean. An example would be nice as well. Thanks

Comment: Here is an example for soft delete with interceptor http://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2014/08/21/soft-delete-mit-entity-framework-6-1.aspx the tutorail in German but the important thing for you is the code or you can find also in english another tutorail.

Comment: Interceptor is cleaner and testable just take a look and when you think this will solve your problem i will post it as answer.

Comment: @BassamAlugili do you happen to have a link in english? thanks

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html